# invoke row-activated with libgda-ui

Tags: c, gtk3, gnome

Can someone provide a sample how to access to callbacks with Gnome-db libgda-ui,  using this demo https://github.com/GNOME/libgda/blob/master/libgda-ui/demos/grid.c and I want to call a callback when I double click on a row like in gtktree with liststore

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution using the raw-grid

```
GtkWidget *grid;
GdauiRawGrid *raw_grid;
g_object_get (G_OBJECT (grid), "raw-grid", &raw_grid, NULL);
```

Then the raw_grid has the callback needed and it have methods like gtk treeview